# Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth vs Microsoft.Identity.Web

Tags: azure

I am new to Microsoft Identity Platform. I see some of the .Net applications are using  Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth for oauth implementations while others use Microsoft.Identity.Web. Please help me understand the difference between these two libraries and the usage scenarios.